# Verify that UITextField does not contain letters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextfield

How can I check the text in my `UITextField` on letters? I want my `UITextField` to include only numeric characters, dashes, + signs, spaces etc, but **NO** letters.

So how do I check if my `UITextField.text` does **not** contain letters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the character set documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CharacterSets.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
if ([myTextField.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"This string contains letters.");
}
```

All of the available character sets are documented here: [NSCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add further benefit and prevent errors, if you are using a storyboard, select your `UITextField` and open the attributes inspector (right hand column with the shield icon at the top) and in the midpoint of that view there are 5 drop down menus, one of which is called `Keyboard`. You have several controllers on there one of which is `Numbers and Punctuation`.

This will set your keyboard to present only numbers and all available punctuation. Combine this with:

```
//SET LEGAL CHARACTERS
NSCharacterSet* tSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:
                        @"abcdef1234567890ABCDEF"];//whatever amount or type of characters you want to use
NSCharacterSet* invSet = [tSet invertedSet]; 

if (yourString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invSet].location != NSNotFound){
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Input Error"
                                message:@"Make sure the value entered is numerical or punctual only."
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

}
```

and you have a simple to use application that prevents the user from accidentally or intentionally causing errors.

Comment: Not quite a technically correct solution, simply because you can paste anything there. Including letters and emojis.

Comment: Great point. I tried this using the accepted response above as a fail safe and with the if statement when the button action is called detects this as is the case in my own app. I use an if/else statement to handle the error with a notification pop up to say why it won't accept. 

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: In numerous apps that I've had to create after this question I used a subclass of UITextField that restricts copy and paste operations along with the type of keyboard you suggested, so this might be the way to go too ;-)

Comment: Care to share that little secret? :-)

See my edited code. This is how I check the intentional errors.

Comment: There are at least 2 good approaches, I'll have them posted shortly

Comment: Great. I look forward to seeing.